# How could we see that a pseudocomplete space is always pseudocompact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

A space $X$ is called **pseudocomplete** if it has a sequence $\{\mathcal B_n:n \in \omega\}$ of $\mathcal{\pi}$-bases such that for any family $\{B_n: n\in \omega\}$ with $B_n\in \mathcal B_n$ and $\overline{B_{n+1}} \subset B_n$ for each $n\in \omega$, we have $\bigcap B_n\not= \emptyset$.

**How could we see that a pseudocomplete space  is always pseudocompact?**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any separation axioms? $T_3$ seems natural, or Tychonoff so get rid of the possible confusion about pseudocompactness.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: I will assume $X$ is Tychonoff.

Comment: The implication is the other way around, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Engelking (3.10) it is shown that for a Tychonoff space $X$ pseudocompactness is equivalent to:

> Every countable family $\mathcal{O}$ of open sets of $X$ with the finite intersection property has the property that $\cap \{ \overline{O}: O \in \mathcal{O} \}$ is non-empty.

So a pseudocompact Tychonoff space is pseudocomplete: just take the any $\pi$-base, repeated $\omega$ many times as the sequence, and if we have a family of non-empty open subsets $(B_n)$ with $\overline{B_{n+1}} \subset B_n$ for all $n$, then this forms a countable family of open sets with the FIP (due to nestedness) and $\cap_n B_n = \cap_n \overline{B_n}$ and the latter is non-empty by pseudocompactness.

The reverse does *not* hold: take any non-compact complete metric space: all complete metric spaces are pseudocomplete, as are all locally compact Hausdorff spaces. So $\mathbb{R}$ in the usual topology is pseudocomplete but not pseudocompact.

Comment: Happy to help out!